# Whats the best way to stop the audio from playing?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

```js
let snare = new Audio (`snare.mp3`);
let kick = new Audio (`kick.mp3`);
let hihat = new Audio (`hihat.mp3`);
let arr =[snare,kick,hihat];
let divs = document.querySelectorAll(`div`);
let body = document.querySelector(`body`);


body.addEventListener(`keydown`,(e)=>{
    if(e.key ===`d`){
        console.log(`ITS ${e.key}`);
        e.stopPropagation();
        arr[0].play()
    }
    if(e.key ===`f`){
        console.log(`ITS ${e.key}`)
        arr[1].play()
    }
    if(e.key ===`g`){
        console.log(`ITS ${e.key}`);
        arr[2].play()
    }
})
```

```css
div {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="music.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    
<div id="d">d</div>
<div id="f">f</div>
<div id="g">g</div>

    <script src="music.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello, currently I'm trying to make a drum kit , where you would press the button and a different type of sound would play. But I run into a problem where if I keep pressing the same button the previous EventListener wouldnt stop playing. So my question is whats the best way to solve this problem? For example , what I want to do is keep mashing the same `F` button, to get the sound played repeatedly. But right now it doesnt play if the previous sound hasnt ended. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: add a "current" variable, set it to whatever gets triggered by your keys, and make sure to run `current.stop()` at the start of a key press.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your script in another way to reach your goal. Here is my script:

```js
let audiArr = [
    {
        source: "snare.mp3",
        buttonKey: "d"
    },
    {
        source: "kick.mp3",
        buttonKey: "f"
    },
    {
        source: "hihat.mp3",
        buttonKey: "g"
    }
];

let body = document.querySelector(`body`);
let currentAudio = [];

body.addEventListener(`keydown`,(e)=>{
    playSound(e.key);
});

function playSound(keyArgu) {
    let keyArr;
    let audioContainer;
    audiArr.forEach(ele => {
        keyArr = ele.buttonKey;
        if (keyArr == keyArgu) {
            audioContainer = new Audio (ele.source);
            currentAudio.push( audioContainer );
            stopPlay(currentAudio);
            audioContainer.play();
        }
    });
}

function stopPlay(currentAudioArgu) {
    let lengVar = currentAudioArgu.length;
    for (let index = 0; index < lengVar -1; index++) {
        currentAudioArgu[index].pause();
    }
}
```

I first grouped each `key` with the corresponding `sound` in an array of objects, then I used `playSound()` function to determine if the special key was pressed at first with the help of `stopPlay()` function pause other sounds and then play the sound that is related to this key. The role of `currentAudio` array is important to reach your goal, it stores the list of last audios and by pressing new key it pauses them.